# How to Read Synapse Analytics SQL Script (JSON Format) as a SQL Script in an IDE?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse

I have a Synapse Git Project that has SQL Scripts created in the Azure Portal like so [Microsoft Docs SQL Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/author-sql-script)and the challenge is that in GIT they appear as this kinda bulky JSON file and I would love to read it as SQL File DBEAVER or IntelliJ …

Any way to do this without having to manually select the Query Section of the file and kinda clean it?

Comment: did you find a good way?  I've been looking myself. I ended up writing a Python Script. But 1.) That requires downloading each .json file one by one 2.) It seems crazy that one should have to fire up Python to do this....

Comment: Hi, sorry have not unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Some Background**

Synapse stores all artifacts in JSON format. In the Git repo, they are in the following folder structure:

[image: Synapse Git Folders]

Inside each folder are the JSON files that define the artifacts. Folder *sqlscript* contains the JSON for SQL Scripts in the following format:

[image]

**NOTE:** the Synapse folder of the script is just a property - this is why all SQL Script names have to be unique across the entire workspace.

**Extracting the script**

The workspace does allow you to Export SQL to a .sql file:
[image]

There are drawbacks: you have to do it manually, 1 file at a time, and you cannot control the output location or SQL file name.

To pull the SQL back out of the JSON, you have to access the *properties.content.query* property value and save it as a *.sql* file. As far as I know, there is no built in feature to automatically save a Script as SQL. Simple Copy/Paste doesn't really work because of the *\n*s.

I think you could automate at least part of this with an Azure DevOps Pipeline (or a GitHub Action). You might need to copy the JSON file out to another location, and then have a process (Data Factory, Azure Function, Logic App, etc.) read the file and extract the query.

Answer (score 0):

We can copy .sql file to git location but yes it is manual process.
[image]

Atleast it helps to push .sql file to Azure Devops git repo.